# How to sum all values in a returned column Cypher?

Tags: cypher

I have written the following Cypher query.

```
MATCH (c:Customers {name:'Paul Pogba'})-[:ORDERED]->(o:Orders)-[:BOUGHT]->(i:Items) Return c, i.kit, count(i)
```

I get a table like this as my output.

```
╒═════════════════════╤═════════════╤══════════╕
│"c"                  │"i.kit"      │"count(i)"│
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"bumper"     │1         │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"wing mirror"│1         │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"bonnet"     │1         │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"boot"       │2         │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"wheel"      │1         │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"windscreen" │1         │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":"Paul Pogba"}│"door"       │1         │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

How to sum all values in column "count(i)" using Cypher in neo4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forcing the split by returning `c, i.kit, count(i)`. And what graph database does absolutely makes sense. To get aggregate just return `count(i)`

And if for some odd reason you seek to get the result you are asking.

```
MATCH (c:Customers {name:'Paul Pogba'})-[:ORDERED]->(o:Orders)-[:BOUGHT]->(i:Items)
WITH collect(DISTINCT c) AS _c, collect(DISTINCT i) AS _i, count(i) AS count_i
UNWIND _c AS c
UNWIND _i AS i
RETURN c, i.kit, count_i
```

Comment: I need to sum all values in column "count(i)" 
(1+1+1+2+1+1+1), how can I do it ?